# How to Bundle and minify the js and css files dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

In my CMS application using MVC, I want to bundle and minify the js and css files dynamically in a controller with a default name and i will add it this name in the view.

can any one help me.